# Where can I find a list of Android features that are deprecated by newer features?

Tags: android, android-fragments, deprecated

Is there something in the Android developers site that shows what is deprecated by a certain addition to the API?

For instance, how can a person tell what is deprecated by Fragments?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Update

The new release notes are available at the new URL here in a more human readable format  -

https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11

The old URL still works with API levels, but for some reason the older versions downloads a tar file instead with the webpage source, probably because they are archived.
Additionally, you don't need `.html` at the end of the URL anymore. So the new API diff URL would be
https://developer.android.com/sdk/api_diff/30/changes

### Original Post

There is always a change report whenever they release a new API, I m putting the link for latest change report for Android 4.0

http://developer.android.com/sdk/api_diff/14/changes.html

There is a section where its mentioned the added and changed packages. You can click on particular package and get to know about deprecated classes and changed methods.
If you need change report of earlier versions, just reduce the no. (14) in the link and you'll get those change reports.
Hopefully this will answer your question.

Comment: Thank you, this comes very close to what i was looking for.

Answer (score 5):

If you make the javadocs yourself from the source code, it'll include a list of deprecated methods & classes - for example: http://www.androidjavadoc.com/2.3/index.html & click  Deprecated at the top

However, getting the reverse (the answer to 'what does this class deprecate?') requires reading through the documentation for whatever classes are involved.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. For instance, if you look at the documentation for the [ActivityGroup](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityGroup.html), you'll notice they've given a warning that it's deprecated because of fragments.

Comment: Yeah, but i was wanting a full list of deprecations because of another addition. Instead of having to go look for them individually.

Comment: I do something similar to this however I do a search for "this class is deprecated". Like so http://developer.android.com/search.html#q=Thisclassisdeprecated&t=0  
As you mentioned it is a bit painful because there are multiple pages in the search result, and it does not show what API it was deprecated in. However if you do a bit more digging you can find that out too.  EDIT sorry for the link ... but i couldn't figure how to get the query in a comment without removing the spaces in the search.

Answer (score 3):

I know it's not an exhaustive list as you want but if you look at api level overview, you will have a good view of the major changes (and so deprecation), for example on 3.0:
http://developer.android.com/sdk/android-3.0.html